# Oracle JDev - ADF Skinning - StyleClass not reflecting

Tags: oracle, stylesheet, skinning, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I use Oracle ADf framework, and I use skins.xml.

Whenever I add some new styleClass in my css, I will change my id in skins.xml. It did work. Suddenly, I am facing an issue. New styleclasses I added, are not reflecting, even though the version got changed.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show sample code from your trinidad-skins.xml/adf-faces-skins.xml (depending on impl) and trinidad-config.xml?  Also: When you add a new style, are you able to see them if you perform a new build and deploy?  What is your setting for the org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION context param in your web.xml?  When you mention version, are you referring to the id value entered into the **-skins.xml file or some other version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, IE has this limitation of 4000 classes per style sheet. As mine crossed, it did not come up.

Thanks all.

Comment: Excellent warning. It's such a pity that ADF / Faces is so verbose.